# Skills that are a must-have requirement

Tags: grammatical-number

Sentence reads "computer programming skills is a must, particularly with Language A and Language B"

I'm fairly certain this should say the programming skills ARE a must, on account of skills being a plural. However, I had the thought that the skills are one requirement, so should in fact be referred to in the singular...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  Replace must with other words and you’ll clearly be able to tell “is” doesn’t work and “are” does.

Ex.  Computer skills IS awesome.
Computer skills ARE awesome.

Ex.  Computer skills IS a great thing to possess.
Computer skills ARE a great thing to possess.

Comment: Cee Jaco is absolutely  and incontrovertibly correct. Whoever marked him or her down should explain themselves or correct their keyboard mistake.

Comment: @Anton If you're right and he is correct he should get your up-vote. He's got mine. Voting for it saves me time from copying and pasting it below.

Comment: Your reasonable wish is my command. Thanks!